# No oauth client details found for https://{domain}.net/ and oauthClientId {id}

Tags: oauth-2.0, jira, jira-rest-api

I trying get oauth access token for add on.I followed this guideline https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/oauth-2-jwt-bearer-tokens-for-apps/. I am getting `No oauth client details found for https://{domain}.net and oauthClientId {id}` error. Can anyone help me on this?

Request:

> url="https://auth.atlassian.io/oauth2/token",
>   headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Host"=>"auth.atlassian.io", "Accept"=>"application/json"}}
>   method=>"post",
>   body=>"grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&scope=READ+WRITE+ACT_AS_USER&assertion={jwt_assertion}"

jwt_assertion config:

> {
>    iss: "urn:atlassian:connect:clientid:#{clientid}",
>      sub: 'urn:atlassian:connect:userkey:{userkey}', 
>      tnt: 'https://{domain}.atlassian.net',
>      aud: 'https://auth.atlassian.io',
>      iat: issued_at,
>      exp: expires_at
>   }

I have tried `urn:atlassian:connect:useraccountid` instead of `urn:atlassian:connect:userkey`

Still got the same error.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you and was going to ask the same question. It seems they're still working on these features but I'm certain there's a way to make this work...

Comment: still i cant find the soltion for this, I raised the ticket in the developer community still about this https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/no-oauth-client-details-found-for-https-domain-net-and-oauthclientid-id/22315